# Is there a way to check if any existing object contains a specific string paramater?

Tags: c#, string, class, object

Alright, so here- I have three objects.

```
public static module foo = new module("John", "A");
public static module bar = new module("Nick", "B");
public static module qux = new module("Alex", "C");
```

This is my class for the object,

```
    public class module
    {
        string moduleName { get; set; }
        string moduleType { get; set; }
        public module(string gName, string gType)
        {
            moduleName = gName;
            moduleType = gType;
        }

        public string print()
        {
            return gName;
        }
    }
```

My question is; how would I check if a user input (string) matches a paramater such as moduleType and returns said module?

For example;

```
string gInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Let's say the user inputs "A", how could I make a method that would check every object's `moduleType`and if a module does have the `moduleType` `"A"`, which in this case is `foo`; would return "John" by using the `.print()` method.

How could I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save those objects into a list

```
List<module> list = new List<module> {
     new module("John", "A"),
     new module("Nick", "B"),
     new module("Alex", "C")
};
```

and then filter out by the user input:

```
var obj = list.Where(m => m.moduleType == userInput).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as is, you can compare with each object's `ModuleType` property to see which one matches.

```
var gInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (foo.ModuleType == gInput)
    Console.WriteLine(foo.ModuleName);
if (bar.ModuleType == gInput)
    Console.WriteLine(bar.ModuleName);
if (qux.ModuleType == gInput)
    Console.WriteLine(qux.ModuleName);
```

But this smells of bad design. It doesn't make much sense to have a bunch of pre-initialized object instances as class properties. A better design would be to have these objects as a list, and see which one in the list - if at all - match the input.

```
var list = new List<Module>
{
    new Module("John", "A"),
    new Module("Nick", "B"),
    new Module("Alex", "C")
};
var gInput = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ModuleType == gInput)?.ModuleName);
```

---

### EDIT: LINQ Crash Course

The `FirstOrDefaul(x => x.ModuleType == gInput)` is using `LINQ` to get this done. Let's break it down.

The list in question is of type `Module`.

When you do `list.FirstOrDefault()` without anything within the brackets, it will return the first item in the list, and failing that (in case there were no items in the list), either `null` or default value for that data type. For example, if the list were a simple `int` list, then it'll return the default value of `int` which is zero in case list is empty. But this is a list of `Module`, so if it were empty it'll return `null`. But in our case we have a non-empty list so it will return an instance of `Module`, the first one in the list.

Now, we can do more than just returning the first item. We can return the first item *that matches a condition*. In your case you want to find the item where `ModuleType` matches user input.

So we use

```
list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ModuleType == gInput)
```

Here, `x` refers to any item in the list of type `Module` (kind of similar to mathematical usage of `X` for unknown terms in an equation). So this reads in English like, find item `x` from the `list` such that `ModuleType` of `x` is equivalent to `gInput`.

So if it exists, it will return an object of type `Module` whose `ModuleType` matches user input.

Comment: When code is plugged in, "ModuleType" ins underlined as an error,


" 'module' does not contain a definition for 'ModuleType' and no accessible extension method 'ModuleType' accepting a first argument of type 'module' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: C# is case sensitive. You'll need to change to `moduleType`.

Comment: Thank you! I also had to change the strings to public.
Do you mind walking me through on how this works? I understand list, but what is FirstOrDefault and what is the `x => x` code?

Comment: Ah, thank you! It makes much more sense now. Is there any way that I can add a variable name to the module? Like how it was originally `module foo = new module()` and now it's `new module()`, is there anyway to add a variable to that object or no?